# Start a Service from another Service and pass-by-value

Tags: android, service, pass-by-value

I've got a Service in my Android application. During onStartCommand, I pass the Service object to another class. Then, from there, there's a thread that after 30 seconds starts another Service. It is something like this:

```
public class FooService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass(this);
        mc.testMethod();
        stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

And this is MyClass:

```
public class MyClass {

    private Service service;

    public MyClass(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void testMethod() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20*1000);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(service, BarService.class);
                    service.startService(intent);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // CATCH!
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Now, as you can see, in FooService I call stopSelf() wich destroys that Service object. By the way MyClass has got a copy of that Service that was passed by value. After 20 seconds, we can start BarService from MyClass. I've tested it and it works but I can't understand why! The way I wrote the code is dirty (for me). Is it correct to start another service from one that was destroyed? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Reference keeping. Just normal. You should use the AlarmManager for this.

Comment: @SoothSayer It is not a reference (or pointer, or whatever). Java is pass by value, it means that the object itself is destroyed, but I've got a _copy_ of that service even if it is not in a started state. It is a theory problem: is it correct to start another Service from one that I've destroyed using stopSelf()? I've implemented an AlarmManager but, right now, I'm updating everytime the Service object inside MyClass.

Comment: Use Handler with Messenger and keep updating your service through activity.

Comment: Java is not a pass by value, I mean, yes but it's not so simple. And stopSelf() != destroyed object. IMO, start another service from a stopped service is not a good idea. Works because your service is stopped but still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tested it and it works but I can't understand why

It works today on the environments you tested in. It may not work in all environments (e.g., ROM mods) and may not work tomorrow (e.g., Android OS updates). A destroyed `Context`, such as your stopped service, should not be used for anything. It *happens* that *presently* you can still use it to call `startService()` later, but that behavior is not guaranteed.

> Is it correct to start another service from one that was destroyed?

No. In this case, I fail to see why you need two services in the first place.

> I've got a copy of that service

No, you do not.

Comment: So, at this point, I think that I'm going back and confusing pass by reference, pass by value...

Comment: @Angelo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference In a nutshell, `service` in your `MyClass` constructor is a pointer to a `Service` object. That *pointer* is copied (pass-by-value) from its original location (`this` in your service). The underlying *object* is *not* copied.

Comment: I read that damn link too many times :D So, pass by value means that the pointer is copied, not the object itself. Good! So, even if I call stopSelf() (as pointed out from SoothSayer) the Service object is not destroyed, I still have a reference in MyClass and GC will not destroy it... BUT it isn't available in the Android Environment. It still works only because the object is somewhere in my stack, right?

Comment: @Angelo: "even if I call stopSelf() (as pointed out from SoothSayer) the Service object is not destroyed" -- yes it is, in terms of the use of the verb "destroy" in Android. `onDestroy()` will be called on the `Service` after `stopSelf()`, and the `Service` object should no longer be used after that point. "I read that damn link too many times" -- personally, I think it is easier for most Java developers to think of Java objects as being pass-by-reference, with Java primitives being pass-by-value.

Comment: @Angelo: "It still works only because the object is somewhere in my stack, right?" -- it still works only because `stopSelf()`, and the behavior it triggers, does not mess up the `Service` enough to cause it to fail to work when you call `startService()` on it. However, again, that's subject to change by anyone with the source code to `Service`, such as device manufacturers, ROM modders, and Google itself. Hence, don't rely on `startService()` working on a destroyed `Service`.

Comment: ok we've understood each other, "destroyed" was meant as "destroyed from memory and deallocated", not the "onDestroy()" call etc...

p.s: I'm using FooService and BarService because they do different things in their onStartCommand()! (you were asking why I'm using two Services)

Comment: @Angelo: You can still have on service. Use an `if` statement in `onStartCommand()`, branching based on an extra in the `Intent`.

Comment: I know it should be asked elsewhere but it's about the Service pass-game... in MyClass I need a context. As it always changes, should I use the ApplicationContext or update each time the Service context in MyClass?

Comment: @Angelo: If an instance of `MyClass` is only used by one `Service`, use the `Service`. If an instance of `MyClass` may be used by multiple components (e.g., it's a singleton), use `getApplication()` to retrieve the `Application` and use it, to avoid a memory leak.